# Android Notification builder sound doesn't work

Tags: android

I have tried many things suggested here, but nothing works for me.
here is my source code:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle("title")
.setContentText("Hello World!");
mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

The notification appears but no sound, any help ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, please share if you found a solution

Comment: my problem was because I did write `mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);`. This line make `mBuilder.setSound` effectless .

Answer (score 24):

Set the default flags:

```
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
```

Comment: `mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)` should work as well.

Answer (score 5):

Use **notification.sound** instead of mBuilder.setSound() solved my problem.

Here is the code -

```
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: i was able to use mBuilder.setSound() from within the debugger with a break point after setting the sound, but without the break point no sounds would be issued. But this method works with and without the debugger. Thanks.

Comment: This fixed things for me on Samsung devices. :)

Comment: If someone still doesn't have sound after this or some other anser, go to Settings/ Notifications/App notifications and find the app you test and check if any notification setting is disabled for this specific app.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see anything wrong in the way you are setting the sound. Another alternative way is to set the sound the following way. Give it a go and see if it helps...

```
Uri alertSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle("title")
.setContentText("Hello World!")
.setSound(alertSound);
```

**Updated**
Please try editing the `NotificationManager` as follows and try...

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = mBuilder.getNotification();
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; // cancel the notification when clicked by the user
mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Why don't you just test playing a sound first by simply calling `Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
r.play();` on a button click and see if it works.

Comment: And are you testing it on a device or an emulator? My recommendation is to test on an actual device.

Comment: I am testing on a real device. samsung galaxy tab2.

Comment: ohhh what you suggested to play the sound alone worked. It's a nice start.

Comment: Hmm. Then it might be the way the `notify` is being called.

Comment: Is the notification appearing?

Comment: You're not in vibrate or silent mode are you, by any chance? The notification audio stream will be muted in that case.

Comment: Sure, not! Anyway, inside the notification function I played the sound as neo suggested above, well it does work however it's not right.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing my sound settings did it. Notification level was all the way down to zero.

It's tricky because other sounds will work except notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This can also because of minor incompatibility with older API version. For example, when compiling on SDK 25 but targeting older version (e.g. SDK 15), I added the following line to fix the problem:

```
notification.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM;
```